# VBA - Macro Recorder to change cell colors not working as intended

Tags: excel, vba

I used the macro recorder to change some parts of a text in a cell as the same color as the background which "hides" that part. E.g. for "Text Here 1", the "1" is changed to the same color as the background so users would only see "Text Here" for visual purposes. However, reusing this macro gives an unintended color. The cell background color is RGB (226, 239, 218)

Before macro is run:

[image]

Intended Result:

[image]

Unintended Result:

[image]

```
Sub Macro1()

    Range("D6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Text Here 1"
    With ActiveCell.Characters(start:=1, Length:=10).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Size = 20
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    
    With ActiveCell.Characters(start:=11, Length:=1).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Size = 20
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
End Sub
```

Edited code that was trimmed down from the macro recorder:

```
Sub Macro2()
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ws.Cells(6, 4).Characters(start:=11, Length:=1).Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why that's happening but you could always get rid of the stuff that's been recorded but not really needed.

```
With Range("D6")
    .Characters(Start:=11, Length:=1).Font.Color = .Interior.Color
End With
```